# Hard example in PSL(2,F)

Tags: group-theory

Would anyone could give an example of a finite subgroup $A$ of the $PSL(2,F)$, where $F$ is an infinite locally finite field of odd characteristic, with centralizer $C_{PSL(2,F)}(A)=A$?

Thanks!

Comment: Like a subgroup of order $3$ in $PSL(2,3)$?

Comment: Probably "an finite" was supposed to be "an infinite" and so F doesn't work any more. Toral (split or not) subgroups don't work either. I haven't thought about analogues of A4, S4, and A5, but they seem pretty plausible.

Comment: But if the centralizer of $A$ is $A$, then $A$ has to be abelian.

Comment: User2040: Sorry! F is infinite!

Comment: @DerekHolt: oh sorry, I was thinking the centralizer contained in A. If A is abelian, then I don't think such a thing exists, right? A finite abelian $p'$-group A is diagonalizable over the algebraic closure, so contained in a maximal torus (split or not) which centralizes it, a finite $p$-subgroup has the entire field as a centralizer. I don't think PSL(2,F) has any mixed (non-identity $p$ and $p'$ Sylows) abelian subgroups, since the field is self-centralizing.